# Rotate PDF file in Reader in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

How can I rotate a PDF file that was opened in the Reader app in Windows 8?

In particular, where is the "toolbar" of that app? I can only see the zoom buttons and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the reader and you will see a bottom bar with some options. Click on **More** options and you will get the rotate option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do a right mouse click and you will see the options.
Hit the "..." button at the bottom right and rotate.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the shortcut **ctrl + r**

Comment: A little more from an answer is expected then just saying to use a shortcut.